# Unique integer solution to $a+b+c=79,\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c =\frac17$

Tags: number-theory

If $a, b, c$ are integers such that
$$
\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac17,\\
a+b+c = 79,\\
a<b<c
$$
what is the unique trio solution $(a,b,c)$?

Comment: Something got cut down, the inequality between a,b, and c is a<b<c.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please tell us what you've tried, what progress you've made, and where you're stuck. Otherwise you are at risk for being downvoted and/or having the question closed.

Comment: Brute force gives no trio :(

Comment: @Gribouillis Did you consider negative $a$ as well?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No I looked only $0 < a < b < c$

Comment: One approach is to write the second as $a=79-b-c$, substitute that into the first, and view it as a quadratic in $b$.  Plug into the quadratic formula.  Now just try all the $c$s.  If you look at the square root term in the quadratic formula you might find some restriction on $c$ to make it come out integral.

Comment: Actually, if one of the trio is allowed to be negative, there is a very easy solution. More difficult to prove it unique though.

Comment: We also know that if $a \lt 0, b \lt 14$ so there are not many to try.  Similarly, if $a \gt 0, a \lt 21$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Could you explain why?

Comment: $$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac17 \iff \iff \frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}=\frac17 \iff {7(ab+bc+ca)}{}=abc $$ $$\iff {7a(b+c)}{}=abc-7bc=bc(a-7) \ [1]$$

$$a+b+c=79 \iff b+c=79-a \ [2]$$

[1]+[2]

$$7a(79-a)=bc(a-7)$$

thus

$$bc=\frac{7a(79-a)}{(a-7)}$$  wich integer solutions are: a=0 and a=79

Comment: @B.Mehta:  If $a$ is negative, $\frac 1b + \frac 1c \gt \frac 17$ and $\frac 1b$ is the greater.  If $a$ is positive and $21$ or greater the sum of the reciprocals will be less than $\frac 17$

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer - I've reduce the case to a limited set of values for the values amogst $a,b,c$ which are not divisible by $7$, and a separate (much larger) list for the $a,b,c$ which are divisible by $7$.

Since $ab+ac+bc=abc\left(\frac 1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)=\frac{abc}{7}$, you have that at least one of the $a,b,c$ has to be divisible by $7$.  Since the sum is $79,$ not all of them can be divisible by $7$.

Assume $a$ is not divisible by $7$. (We aren't sorting the answers yet.)

We know that $$p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-79x^2+\frac{abc}{7}x-abc$$ From $p(a)=0$ we deduce, by factoring out the $a$:

$$bc=a^2-79a+\frac{abc}{7}$$

or $bc(a-7)=7a(a-79).$

But this means that $a-7$ is a factor of $7a(a-79)$. But since $a$ is not divisible by $7$, we know that $\gcd(a-7,7)=1$ and $(a-7,a)=1,$ so we have that $a-7\mid a-79$, or $a-7\mid 72$.

This means that $$a-7\in\{-72,-36,-24,-18,-12,-9,-8,-6,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36,72\}$$

or $$a\in\{-65,-29,-17,-11,-5,-2,-1,1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,15,16,19,25,31,43,79\}$$

We also get:

$$ac(b-7)=7b(b-79)$$

Assuming $b=7b'$ is divisible by $7$, then we get that $b'-1\mid 7(7b'-79)$ or $b'-1\mid 7\cdot 72.$

You can proceed by exhaustion now.

I think I've been able to eliminate the case when $b,c$ are both divisible by $7$. Then you'd have to have $a\equiv 2\pmod{7}$ which restricts to the cases $a=-5,9,16,79.$ It is easy to eliminate $79$. You can eliminate the others with a little work.

So $a,c$ must be in our set above, and $a+c\equiv 2\pmod 7$.

Also, since $\frac{a+c}{ac}=\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{7b'}=\frac{b'-1}{7b'}$ and the left hand side has no multiple of $7$ in the denominator, we have that $b'-1$ must be divisible by $7$.

Also, from $7(ab+ac+bc)=abc$ we see that $a\mid b'c$ and $b'\mid ac$.

That lets you greatly restrict some checks.

For example, if $a=-29$ then $c$ is not divisible by $29$ (since $a\neq c$) and thus $b'$ must be divisible by $29$. Since $b'=7b''+1$ for some $b''\mid 72$, you also need $b''\equiv 4\pmod{29}$, or $b''=4$. This give $b=7\cdot 29$, $a=-29$ and $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{4}{29}+\frac{1}{29}=\frac{5}{29}$ which not a solution.

More generally, you need:

$$\frac{a+c}{ac}=\frac{b''}{7b''+1}$$

Since the right side is reduced to lowest terms, you get that $b''\mid a+c$. (We already saw that $b'=7b''+1\mid ac.$)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: $a, b, c$ are roots of the polynomial

$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = x^3 - 79 x^2 + \frac{p}{7}x - p =0$$
where $p = a b c$. It follows that $7 | p x$, hence one of the numbers is a multiple of $7$.

Edit: Using @ThomasAndrews' answer, I showed by a direct computation that
there are no solutions. The idea is the following: suppose $a$ is known,
then we know
$$b + c = 79 - a := s \qquad \frac{s}{b c} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{a}:= u$$
It follows that $b c = \frac{s}{u}$, and $b$ and $c$ satisfy the
quadratic equation
$$x^2 - s x + \frac{s}{u}$$
The discriminant is $\Delta = s^2 - 4 \frac{s}{u}$.

The following python program computes all these discriminants. None of them has a rational square root.

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import sqrt


base = [
    -65, -29, -17, -11, -5,
    -2, -1, 1, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 13, 15, 16, 19,
    25, 31, 43,
]

def work():
    for a in base:
        u = Fraction(1, 7) - Fraction(1, a)
        s = Fraction(79 - a, 1)
        bc = s / u
        delta = s**2 - 4 * bc
        assert delta.denominator == 1
        yield delta.numerator

print list(work())
```

The resulting list of discriminants is

```
[17096, 9228, 7312, 6560, 6076,
6057, 6120, 6448, 7372, 8425,
10656, 17593, -10863, -3920, -1679,
-612, 352, 736, 833, 940, 816, 568, 92]
```

Comment: The fact that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{7}$ already guarantees that, of course.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes but other simple results are possible, for example by writing $79=7+72$, we see that apart from $7$, the only possible prime divisors of $x - 7$ are $2$ and $3$.